# Question foreach on arrays returned by functions

Tags: php, loops

i wonder if i do

```
foreach (func_to_return_array() as $item) { ... }
```

will it call `func_to_return_array()` many times (the array length)? if it does i guess it will be better to use

```
$arr = func_to_return_array();
foreach ($arr as $item) { ... }
```

Comment: I've asked this before. The accepted answer offers an explanation as to how it works, so it's a good supplementary read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685689/php-how-is-an-array-in-a-foreach-loop-read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will only call `func_to_return_array()` once. Example:

```
foreach (foo() as $v) {
  echo "$v\n";
}

function foo() {
  echo "Called foo\n";
  return range(1, 5);
}
```

Output:

```
Called foo
1
2
3
4
5
```