# PHP foreach(...) question

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I was wondering if using

```
foreach(get_some_array() as $boo) do_something...
```

is slower than

```
$arr = get_some_array();
foreach($arr as $boo) do_something...
```

I mean would get_some_array() be called like 10000000 times if the array would have so many elements (in the 1st example) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: how is an array in a foreach loop read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685689/php-how-is-an-array-in-a-foreach-loop-read)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that function will be called just 1 time.
You can verify this by doing:

```
<?php
function get()
{
    echo "getting\n";

    return array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
}

foreach (get() as $v) {
    echo $v . "\n";
}
?>
```

Here it outputs:

```
murilo@mac:regionais$ php -f teste.php 
getting
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

$arr = get_some_array(); theoretically adds zero time to this equation, so it really wont make a difference what you use here.