# Is this code ineffective/slow?

Tags: php, performance, foreach, micro-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is an array in a PHP foreach loop read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685689/how-is-an-array-in-a-php-foreach-loop-read)

If I have this function:

```
function getList()
{
   $list = array();
   $list['foo'] = 'Foo';
   $list['bar'] = 'Bar';
   return $list;
}
```

And then I do this:

```
foreach ( getList() as $item )
{
     echo $item.'<br>';
}
```

Will that code be slower than doing this:

```
$list = getList();
foreach ( $list as $item )
{
     echo $item.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Usually when I write a question like this I realize before I click "submit" that I would have spent less time profiling it for myself :)

Comment: The two solution should have roughly the same running time. I've not tested them as I would do I will have a benchmark for the php version I'm using. In similar case, though, I would use the second solution as does not leave room to similar doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
function getList()
{
    echo '<div>getList()</div>';
    $list = array();
    $list['foo'] = 'Foo';
    $list['bar'] = 'Bar';
    return $list;
}

foreach ( getList() as $item )
{
    echo $item.'<br>';
}
?>
```

And you only will get 1 echo, which means getList() only called once :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question...

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure that in your first example, the getList() function inside foreach is only evaluated once.
Thus, there wouldn't be any huge difference.

Update:
As requested, this was a quick test I did in php interactive mode.

```
function getList() {
    echo 'a';
    return array(1,2,3);
}

foreach(getList() AS $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Result: a123

Comment: It would be nice to have some justification behind your answer. "I'm sure" doesn't really cut it.

Comment: @nickb: Putting an echo into `getList()` does cut it though. Though I agree, he should probably mention that in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've put up the test code that I just did to back up my answer.